# Find the general solution of $e^y (\cos xy - y \sin xy)dx + e^y (\cos xy - x \sin xy)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find out whether I screwed up. I used $\mu(x,y)=e^{-y}\cos^{-1}xy$ as an integrating factor:

$$(1-y\tan xy)dx + (1-x\tan xy)dy = 0$$

But since this is an exact differential equation, we can just look for a differentiable field $F$ such that

$$\begin{cases} F_x & = 1-y\tan xy  \\ F_y & = 1-x\tan xy \end{cases}$$

Integrating $F_x$ w.r.t. $x$ we get

$$\int (1-y\tan xy) dx = x + \ln|\cos xy| + \phi(y)$$

When we compute the derivative of this expression w.r.t. $y$ we can infer that $\phi'(y)=1$, so $\phi(y)=y+C$. Hence

$$F(x,y)= x + y + \ln|\cos xy| + C$$

So the general solution is implicitly defined by the one-parameter family of equations $F(x,y)=0$. **Is this correct?** How can I know I did not gain nor lose solutions when multiplying by $\mu(x,y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same answer without integrating factor. So your answer is correct.
$$e^y (\cos xy - y \sin xy)dx + e^y (\cos xy - x \sin xy)dy = 0$$
Since $e^y \ne 0$
$$ (\cos xy - y \sin xy)dx + (\cos xy - x \sin xy)dy = 0$$
$$ \cos xy(dx+dy) -  \sin xy(xdy+ydx)  = 0$$
We have $xdy+ydx=dxy$
$$ \cos xyd(x+y) -  \sin xyd(xy)  = 0$$
$$ d(x+y) -  \tan xyd(xy)  = 0$$
Integrate:
$$x+y+\ln |\cos xy|=C$$